# Parse Python Output in OrgMode to a table

Tags: python, parsing, emacs

I tried now for one hour and I don't get the result I expect, so I need to ask you here:

- I have Emacs 24 installed
- I have Python 3.0 installed

Actually I try to parse a python output to a table via orgmode:

```
#+begin_src python :session :results output table :exports results
print("|Example|")
print("|--------|")
print("|One example entry|")
#+end_src
```

I expect a table when I export the buffer to pdf/html.

However this does not happen.

Can anyone fix my code and tell me, why mine does not work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "However this does not happen." Okay, what *does* happen?

Comment: Oh. Sorry - I actually see what python writes to the output stream so:

|Example|
|-----------|
|One example entry|

But it is not parsed to a table

Comment: There is an example [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/21013/8811) of how to output an org-mode table by returning a list of lists -- no `print('|------|')` necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `raw` to your `:results` header arguments:

```
#+begin_src python :session :results output table raw :exports results
print("|Example|")
print("|--------|")
print("|One example entry|")
#+end_src
```

From [the documentation](http://orgmode.org/manual/results.html):

> `raw` The results are interpreted as raw Org mode code and are inserted directly into the buffer. If the results look like a table they will be aligned as such by Org mode.